# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function Calling JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, listview

I am get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` when I am trying to call my Javacsript function `displayValue()`.

[image: Error message firing when function is called.]

Here is my Javascript code:

```
    var HoC = 0;
    var Rate = 0;

    function getHoursOrCubes(input, control)
    {
        HoC = input;
        var answer = HoC * Rate;
        displayValue(answer);
    }

    function getRate(input, control)
    {
        Rate = input;
        var answer = HoC * Rate;
        displayValue(answer);
    }

    function displayValue(finalValue) {
        var listViewRef = document.getElementById('LV_Tickets');
        var elementArray = listViewRef.getElementsByTagName('Label');
        alert('this worked.');

        for (var i = 0; i < elementArray.length; i++) {
            var elementRef = elementArray[i];

            elementRef.value = finalValue;
            alert(elementRef.value);
        }
    }
```

I believe the line that is throwing the error is `var elementArray = listViewRef.getElementsByTagName('Label');`.

I have a listview inside a listview and I want to set the value of a label in the nested listview. So that is what I am trying to do here.

Here is my asp code for the ListView I am trying to access:

```
<asp:ListView ID="LV_Tickets" runat="server" DataSourceID="SQL_Tickets"  InsertItemPosition="FirstItem" OnPreRender="LV_Tickets_PreRender" DataKeyNames="TicketNum">
```

The `getHoursOrCubes()` function is called in a nested ListView's insertingitem template:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="HoursOrCubesTextBox" runat="server" style="height: 20px; width: 165px;" Text='<%# Bind("HoursOrCubes") %>' onchange="getHoursOrCubes(this.value)" />
```

Comment: Have you debugged with the browser to step through the script and see exactly what variables are something, or nothing? It gives you the line 93 in the error. Check there. But something is nothing.

Comment: Took me a while, but nailed it. You are using `<asp:ListView>` That control is changed as it is rendered by a template. This template gets another id. Set the id of the template identical to that of the `listview` then add `ClientIDMode="Static"` to the listview. Should point you in the right direction. Worked on my machine.

Comment: Alright, I will give this a try. So if the nested listview is inside the selectedindextemplate then I need to set the ID of that template to the same as the parent listview?

Comment: Yes and set the parent with `ClientIDMode="Static"`

Comment: Sorry @Mouser, I was away from my office. This actually did not work out as it would throw an error on the template. But I ended up finding another solution not using any javascript. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var listViewRef = document.getElementById(<%= LV_Tickets.ClientID %>);
    var elementArray = listViewRef.getElementsByTagName('Label');
```

`listViewRef` is a `nodeList` that means it's a collection of nodes. To call the function `getElementsByTagName` you need a node. I selected the first node in the list by `[0]`. This should return a node on which `getElementsByTagName` can be called.

Comment: If I change my code to this, it throws the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefinedNewJob.aspx:93 displayValueNewJob.aspx:81 getHoursOrCubesNewJob.aspx:698 onchange`

Comment: @ChaseErnst that means that there are no elements in the page with the name you're looking for.

Comment: Does the element you're referring to have the name attribute `LV_Tickets`?

Comment: Oh shoot, it has the ID of LV_Tickets. I changed it to `getElementById` but now  it is returning null.

Comment: Now you need to ditch the [0].

Comment: Yes, I have removed the zero, as it is no longer an array. But listViewRef is returning null now. I don't understand how this can happen if I have the ID on the asp control the exact same. I have cleared my cache also.

Comment: In C# generated code you need to reference the client-id.

Comment: That's correct. If the control is of type runat="server". You will need to do something like this - getElementById('<%= txt_name.ClientID %>')

Comment: Still returning null. I have triple checked the name is correct

Comment: @ChaseErnst is the element drawn before the code executes? When is `getHoursOrCubes` called?

Comment: I have updated the question. It is being called inside a nested listview's insertingitemtemplate on the onclick event. So from my understanding there isnt any possible way I can click it before the listview is drawn

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call a function that doesn't exist.

The function`getElementsByName` returns an [IHTMLElementCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa703928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Use the [tags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh870433%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method of that object to get what you want. There is no method for `getElementsByTagName` that operates on the `IHTMLElementCollection`.

Instead of

```
var elementArray = listViewRef.getElementsByTagName('Label');
```

try

```
var elementArray = listViewRef.tags('Label');
```

That should work for you.

Comment: I accidentally was using `getElementsByName` where as I should have been using getElementById. But right now it is returning null on this call.

Comment: I actually ended up solving this problem without using Javascript. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Awesome! Please edit your question to indicate how you solved the problem, or select an answer. Thanks!